# Works in FF but not in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is related with Codeignitor, Ajax and Jquery

Following code works fine in Firefox and for chrome I need to make change in url

like url: create  (This is for Firefox)
like url: users/create  (This is for Chrome and it doesn't work in Firefox)

Please note that I am new to codeignitor so don't know if I made a mistake there

Project is being developed in CodeIgniter

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "create",  
    data: "full_name="+full_name,
    success: function(returned_html){

        //Do Something here

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error with ajax Function: "+ textStatus+" "+errorThrown);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non-relative url because I think Firefox and Chrome does not have the same base path.

```
url : 'http://.../create'
```

Comment: :I have used this way around and it is working fine now...thx for that...but I am still not sure if its correct approach.... as I need to hard code the URL in my js file....though I am using this approach but would like to change to something better where I need not to hard code

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the url depending on the browser and use that in your script

```
if($.browser.chrome) {
    myurl: "users/create";
}else {
    myurl: "create";}
```

Comment: I tried using it in following way 

[code]

    var myurl = "create";

    if($.browser.chrome) {
     myurl = "users/create";
    }

[code]

But its not working

Comment: `$.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: You can use a migration plugin get these features back. Follow this [Migrate older jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)